# Divide image blocks into two chunks

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, svd

I'm working on an image and I divided into non overlapping blocks, what I want to do next is to apply some changes on every two adjacent chunks of the same blocks. For example, I have a block B1 and I divided it into B11 and B12.

The objective here is to apply SVD on B11 and B12 and compare their singular values: `S11(2,2)` and `S12(2,2)` and so on for every other blocks. But I don't know how to work on every two sub-blocks adjacent I only can apply SVD for blocks Bi.

It seems like I need a loop `for` to process every two sub-blocks right or can the function `mat2tiles` do this?

This is an example explaining what I'm saying.

[image: image divided into blocks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way how to get my objective, and I'm sharing in case somebody needed too:

```
%First this a function that help me to divide my image into non overlapping block

function B=Block(IM,p,q)  
p=p    %% number of rows
q=q    %% number of cols
[m,n] = size(IM);
IJ = zeros(p,q);
z = 1;
for m1 = 1:m/p   
for n1 = 1:n/q  
   if m1*p <= m;
    if n1*q <= n;

      for i = (m1-1)*p+1:m1*p
         for j = (n1-1)*q+1:n1*q
             IJ(i-(m1-1)*p,j-(n1-1)*q) = IM(i,j);
           if (i-(m1-1)*p)==p&&(j-(n1-1)*q)==q;
               OUT = IJ;
              B{1,z} = OUT;
              z = z+1;
           end
         end
      end
    end
   end
end 
end
```

Now I will divide each blocks into sub-blocks and apply SVD

```
Block_Num = (m*n)/(p*q) % To get how many blocks we have
fun= @svd % the function we use is SVD
for i=1:Block_Num
sv=blkproc(B{i},[4 4],fun) % in my case I wanted to apply SVD 
                                  of every sub-block of 4*4
 end
```

And this get the job done. hope it will be useful for you too